# C++ -Template class with methods returning template type

Tags: c++, templates, methods, return-type

I have found some topics on templates and methods. But I can't figure out how it applies in my scenario.

```
template <class T>
class SimpleLinkedList {}
```

Let's assume this is my template classe and it contains the method:

```
LinkedNode<T> * next(){};
```

Where LinkedNode is also a Template and uses the class T from SimpleLinkedList template.

The error that is thrown is :

```
Member reference base type "LinkedNode<T>" is not a struct or union.
```

Now I know what a struct or union is, but I can't figure out why my method is wrong.

**edit**

Error seemed to be something completely different.
NVM.

Thanks Demi.

Comment: Not enough information. What is the definition of the `LinkedNode<T>` type?

Comment: Im not sure what you are asking...Please elaborate.

Comment: could you provide more information

Comment: I would like to but, what exactly do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you defined `LinkedNode` not as template in `SimpleLinkedList`. You may try to remove `<T>` in `LinkedNode<T> * next(){}`. Is this works? More information needed.

Comment: Show full `LinkedNode` and `SimpleLinkedList`

Comment: I really don't see how that would help honestly. There should be some convention on how template returns should work?

Comment: Works fine. Do you have `LinkedNode` definition _before_ `SimpleLinkedList`? Your full code compiles fine (VC++ 2010).

Comment: OK I got your problem! Replace `current.next` with `current->next`! and same with `current.previous` to `current->previous`.

Comment: Ok yeah that was stupid. It's fine now. Thanks...I feel like an idiot. Also CLANG auto completion was screwing me over couldn't see any properties.

Answer (score 0):

In the definition of `SimpleLinkedList<T>::next()` you need to use pointer semantics when dereferencing `current->next` as `current` is a pointer, not a reference.

```
LinkedNode<T> * next(){
    if (getSize() == 0 || current.next == NULL) return NULL;
      return current;
};
```

Change to:

```
LinkedNode<T> * next(){
    if (getSize() == 0 || current->next == NULL) return NULL;
      return current;
};
```

Likewise for `previous`.

Comment: Yes, I missed that. Demi pointed it out. But I wouldn't completely blame me =P CLANG as auto completion failed me as well ( using codelite ).

Thanks for the reply though.